# What does this angle-bracket notation in Typescript mean?

Tags: typescript

I see this syntax in Typescript:

```
myFunc<MyType>(myObject)
```

What does it mean?

I understand that `<MyType>myObject` is a type-assertion.
But it makes no sense to me when `<MyType>` is between the function name and the open parenthesis.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: Functions can be templated to work on 'any' class of object. Telling the function the class can make the function operate differently based on the classes own functionality.

Comment: By the way, it's not just TypeScript. Java, Rust, C++, and lots of other statically-typed languages do this.

Comment: _"I understand that <MyType>myObject is a type-assertion."_ - no, **it is not** a type-assertion: while, in isolation, the `<T>` syntax _can_ be used for that, it's a bad idea as it's incompatible with TSX and everyone uses `as` for type-assertions now. But in the context of a method-call-site, as in your code, the `<T>` specifies type-arguments for type-parameters, and is not a type-assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "Generics". You can read more about this in the official documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content